# Shoutbox AJAX problem

Tags: ajax

I'm using [Shoutbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/shoutbox) module, but I got problem. AJAX refresh is working only when I submit a message first, is this possible to enable AJAX refresh automatically on page load?